# Save input data and add icon inside textbox after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to save each input text by its own `id` and append the icon inside that input after ajax succeed.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="form-group has-feedback autosave">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your name"/>
        <i class="form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback autosave">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Your lastname"/>
        <i class="form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('blur', '.autosave input', function(e) { 
//when input inside .autosave was blurred
  var _id=$(this).attr('id');//id
  var _val=$(this).val();//value

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'save.php',
        data: {id:_id,val:_val},//send id and val
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
          $(_id).addClass('fa fa-check');//addclass when succeed
          console.log(data);//debug
        },//success
    });//$.ajax
  });
```

I plan to display the check icon inside each input when the submit succeed. So the idea is getting the `id` and `val` from each input. And send it to db via ajax. After the response, that input will be update with icon with specific `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the element's `id` - you can store the reference to `this` which the function runs under and use that within the `$.ajax` success handler. Try this:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.autosave input', function(e) { 
  var $el = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save.php',
    data: {
      id: $el.prop('id'),
      val: $el.val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $el.addClass('fa fa-check');
      console.log(data); //debug
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: what is wrong with using `ID` ? i think OP just need to add `#` like `$("#"+_id)`?

Comment: There's nothing 'wrong' in the sense that it won't work. However it's slower, ugly and unnecessary when you already have a reference to the element via `this`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your method is working! But the `addClass` after success is not firing. Can this addClass `fa fa-check` to the `i.form-control-feedback` without defining the element???

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, after several testing. I still cannot find the solution to just trigger the `addClass` on it's parent. When success return, all inputs are rendered `fa fa-check` not just only that `input`

Comment: @Wilf you can update the OP with current code you are using to show what change has been done on previous OP

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a big trying. I found the solution. Thanks to @RoryMcCrossan who gave me the starting idea.

**Javascript**
...

```
    success: function(resp) {
        $this.closest('.form-line').find('i').removeClass('fa fa-check').addClass('fa fa-check');               
        $this.closest('.form-group div.form-line').addClass('success has-success');
        console.log(resp); //debug
    },
```

The only different is the process after success. It looks messy, but working. If you have any shorter pattern would be appreciated.

Comment: `.removeClass('fa fa-check').addClass('fa fa-check')` that seems like a redundant line of code